# Is there a way to pass index as parameter to function being mapped onto an array?

Tags: f#

I have a function, `myFunction`, and I am mapping this onto an array `input`. I would like to reference the index of the `array`'s element in `myFunction`. I have looked on a few sites, such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/ and https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ but cannot find anything which passes the index to the mapped function.

Here are the members I am testing with:

```
// functions
    static member StackOverflow0 (input :int[]) :int[] =
        let myFunction (x :int) :int = x + x
        input |> Array.map myFunction 

// incorrect syntax
    static member StackOverflow1 (input :int[]) :int[] =
        let myFunction (index :int, x :int) :int = x + x + index
        Map myFunction <| (seq {0 .. input.Length}, input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.mapi`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#mapi) for that, it does exactly what you need:

```
static member StackOverflow1 (input :int[]) :int[] =
  let myFunction index x = x + x + index
  input |> Array.mapi myFunction
```

Alternatively, you can annotate each element with an index first using [`Array.indexed`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#indexed), and then map over the pairs:

```
static member StackOverflow1 (input :int[]) :int[] =
  let myFunction (index, x) = x + x + index
  input |> Array.indexed |> Array.map myFunction
```

Comment: Awesome. If it's convenient for you, could you point me toward documentation on if a `mapping('T -> 'U -> 'V) -> array: 'T[] -> 'U[] -> 'V[]` function exists?

Comment: That's [`Array.map2`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#map2). Why don't you explore the libraries on your own? That's way more efficient than asking other people every time.

Comment: Probably because I didn't know https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/ existing to explore until now. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint: you can use your IDE integration to explore libraries right in your IDE. In most environments it's enough to type `Array`, then hit a dot, and the IDE will show you what's available.